# VBA removing rows from a spreadsheet if cells contain a certain string

Tags: vba, excel, object

I am very new to VBA. I am trying to isolate a particular customers transactions on a spread sheet.

Column "A" contains the Customer payment method (prepaid or various other methods). Column "D" contains the customer we are shipping too, Column "L" contains the customer we are shipping from.

If the cell in column "A" has 'prepaid' I want to search column "D" for the customer name (jaba). I will then delete all rows which do not contain this customer. IF the cell in column "A" is not  'prepaid' I want it to search column "L" for the customer name, and delete all rows which do not contain this string. When I run the code provided below I get an 1004 error on the following script 'If cell3.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then'. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub DoNotContainClearCells()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim cell3 As Range
Dim ContainWord As String

'What range do you want to search?
  Set rng = Range("A:A")
  Set rng2 = Range("D:D")
  Set rng3 = Range("L:L")
  'What phrase do you want to test for?
  ContainWord = "jaba"

For Each cell In rng

    If cell.Value = "prepaid" Then


        'Loop through each cell in range and test cell contents
        For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
            If cell2.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then EntireRow.Delete
        Next cell2

        Else
        'Loop through each cell in range and test cell contents
        For Each cell3 In rng3.Cells
            If cell3.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then EntireRow.Delete
        Next cell3

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have to loop through all of column A? Once pre-paid has been found once, it will delete all column D entries and once it has found another value it will delete all column L entries and there won't be any reason to continue looking through A. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Agree with @SJR , unless you mean that for every row. Example, If  Cell(A1) = "prepaid" >> check if Cell(D1) = "jaba" >> if yes delete row. If Cell(A1) <> "prepaid" >> check if Cell(L1) = "Jaba" >> if yes delete row. Otherwise, there is really no need for 3 `For` loops

Comment: Due to intricacies on how logistics companies bill their clients the initial for loop is necessary. I may be shipping from Jaba to a third party however I am not interested in this bill as it is prepaid. Thanks

Comment: Shai Rado, It is the opposite, if the row does not contain jaba then I want to erase it. However I think the logic is the same as what I have performed, I assume my script has a syntax error. I realise for loops are computationally heavy and you want the minimum amount of them in your script, in this case I see no other way. Thanks

Comment: This condition: 
_"IF the cell in column "A" is not 'prepaid' I want it to search column "L" for the customer name, and delete all rows which do not contain this string."_
Deletes all bills for shipments to Jaba from TP which are not prepaid. Shouldn't this be the opposite?, i.e. keep this bills and delete the ones for shipments to Jaba from TP which are not prepaid otherwise you'll lose track of the bills pending for payment.

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing the logic of your code, *which is not part of the question*, I can tell you that the

> Run-time error '1004': Object required

in this line:

```
If cell3.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then EntireRow.Delete
```

is because the `EntireRow.Delete` is missing a range *(see [Range.EntireRow Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836(v=office.15).aspx))*

**Solution:** Replace these lines:

```
If cell2.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then EntireRow.Delete
If cell3.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then EntireRow.Delete
```

with these:

```
If cell2.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell2.EntireRow.Delete
If cell3.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell3.EntireRow.Delete
```

Suggest to always have at the top of the modules\classes\userforms:

```
Option Explicit
```

This would have given a `Compile error: Variable not defined` highlighting the error earlier at compiling time *(see [Option Explicit Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855(v=office.15).aspx))*

Comment: Thank you E MM! Great advise!